# Type "()" cannot conform to View

Tags: swiftui

I am new in swiftUI I need to call one method on click of button but I am getting error.

Can anyone help me. And one more thing once I will call api how can I redirect to new screen

method name is **self.register()** which is calling api and validate user is valid or not

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowingWebView: Bool = false
    let webView = WKWebView()
    var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Button(action: {
            isShowingWebView = true
        })
        {
            Text("Login")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingWebView) {
            **self.register()**
        }
        .padding([.horizontal], 100)
        .padding([.bottom, .top], 10)
        .font(.system(size: 20, weight: Font.Weight.bold))
        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.white))
         .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        Spacer()
    }
    .padding()
    
   }
}

    func register() {
        var registerDict = [
            "deviceId":UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString,
            "deviceName": UIDevice.modelName,
            "authCode":"HFua7FUmkB22GNdMV7TZwrU-1sQujTNcvkvBqGnQPIU"
        ]
         Webservice.getInstance().registerUser(parameter: registerDict as NSDictionary)
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Button` initializer is wrong, you closed the rounded bracket before providing the label parameter. In your example (`Text` is not formatted), you can use: `Button("Login") { isShowingWebView = true }`.

Comment: You are applying a sheet to the ```Button```. The sheet needs some content, which should be a ```View```. But you are calling your register function which does not return any content, so I expect that's why you're getting the error. Maybe you should be calling register in your button action function instead.